# Why does .net project sometimes use old version of dll?

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have project Foo1 which is dependent on library Foo2, where Foo2 is dependent on library Foo3.

Foo1 is c# gui application, Foo2 is C++/Cli library, Foo3 is native c++ library

Dlls of Foo2/Foo3 libraries lie in separate folder Lib. 
I noticed, that **sometimes** Foo1 uses old version of Foo2.dll file. It copies dlls from Lib folder to Bin folder, where it keeps executable file, and uses their. When I make changes in Foo3 library, Foo2 project also rebuilds. Dlls were replaced in Lib folder. But they stay not updated in Bin folder, thus main application uses old dlls.

It is piece from Foo1.csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
<Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
<ProjectGuid>{1D3976DD-23E4-4798-80A5-AFA8D34E9342}</ProjectGuid>
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
<AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
<RootNamespace>AuthorProtoNet</RootNamespace>
<AssemblyName>AuthorProtoNet</AssemblyName>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
<FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
<ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
<WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
<TargetFrameworkProfile />
<IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
<!-- Predefined intermediate and output paths, defined for all configurations-->
<IntermediateOutputPath>..\..\Temp\win-$(Platform)-$(Configuration)\$(AssemblyName)\</IntermediateOutputPath>
<OutputPath>..\..\Bin\win-$(Platform)-$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
<PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
<Install>true</Install>
<InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
<UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
<UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
<UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
<UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
<UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
<UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
<MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
<ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
<ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
<UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
<BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
</PropertyGroup>
<Reference Include="Foo2">
     <HintPath>..\..\..\Lib\win-$(Platform) $(Configuration)\Foo2.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Comment: Is "Foo2" another project you control or a third-party library? Is "Foo2" available as a NuGet package?

Comment: @EJoshuaS, Foo2 is my own project. It is not third-party library, which is not available as NuGet package

Comment: That is hard to tell without knowing your project configuration. Do you have all of them in the same solution? If yes what are each project's output path? Would be better if you could share each of your project's project (`.csproj`) file.

Comment: Are all three libraries written in C#?  Are they all built as part of the same solution?  If not, why not?

Comment: @f.nasim, yes of course, I can give some details

Comment: @Loring, Foo1 is c# gui application, Foo2 is C++/Cli library, Foo3 is native c++ library

Comment: What happens if you refer to the project itself (rather than the DLL)?

Comment: @EJoshuaS, Do you mean add reference to project instead reference to dll?

Comment: Yes - I saw similar issues to this when I had accidentally hardcoded a reference to the DLL instead of the project.

Comment: Usually you shouldn't be able to add reference to an unmanaged dll or project. Did you edit the project file yourself to do so?

Comment: @f.nasim, Yes, I edit csproj manually, because I should use different dll due platform configurations (in case of release/debug configurations)

Comment: @EJoshuaS, it is valuable thought

Comment: It doesn't look like all three projects are in the same solution.  I recommend that you put them in the same solution - things will be easier. 
I haven't worked with managed C++ libraries but when I've worked with C# and native C++ libraries, I know that C# apps can reference C# libraries but not native C++ libraries.  This means that Visual Studio will handle copying the C# libraries but you have to get the C++ libraries to their final destination on your own (either by setting the output directory appropriately or  using a build event.)

Comment: @Loring, Note that I am using c++/cli library - it is wrapper of native c++ library. .

Comment: Try adding a post build event. You can do so from your C# project's properties or by adding a post-build target in your project's `.csproj` file.

Comment: Crystal ball says that it is actually Foo3.dll that is stale.  Hard to see the difference because Foo2 is just a wrapper.  MSBuild cannot copy it automatically and you did not mention what you do to get it copied so it is most likely the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

*MSBuild* (Visual Studio's default build engine) doesn't add reference to unmanaged libraries and projects (e.g. C++ libraries or projects.), hence they are not copied to project's output directory. The usual solution to copy unmanaged libraries is with a *post-build event*. Post-build event is the user configured DOS commands that MSBuild executes after a project is built.

You can set a project's post-build events in its post-build event editor; you will find that in a project's *Properties > Build Events > Post-build event command line*. Additionally, the MSBuild DOS prompt can access all build variables (e.g `$(Configuration)`, `$(Platform)`, etc.) So configuring the appropriate source and destination paths according to build configuration shouldn't be a problem. In your case something like the following post-build configuration (untested) should work.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostBuildEvent>xcopy \qy ..\..\..\Lib\win-$(Platform) $(Configuration)\Foo2.dll $(OutDir)</PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

P.S. The post-build event editor will generate the preceding section for you. Not necessarily needed to create that yourself.